# Creating pdf using kile. Want png files continuously

Tags: pdf, latex, png

I am creating a pdf file using kile. In my file i have 5 .png files. I need this files in continuous pages. My code is:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=20cm,height=30cm,keepaspectratio]{./Chapters/Chapter6/tab1.png}
\end{figure}
 \newpage
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=20cm,height=30cm,keepaspectratio]{./Chapters/Chapter6/tab2.png}
  \end{figure}
\newpage
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=20cm,height=30cm,keepaspectratio]{./Chapters/Chapter6/tab3.png}
  \end{figure}
\newpage
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=20cm,height=30cm,keepaspectratio]{./Chapters/Chapter6/tab4.png}
  \end{figure}
\newpage
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=20cm,height=30cm,keepaspectratio]{./Chapters/Chapter6/tab5.png}
\caption{Proposed new tagset}
\label{1}
\end{figure}
\newpage
```

I get the output pdf containing this png files in different pages ie. not in continuous pages. Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the preamble, include

```
\usepackage{float}
```

and then for your figures, use the `H` option.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[...]{...}
\end{figure}
```

As described in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions, the `H` placement says to insert the float at the precise location that it appears in the text, so you should be able to put them all on consecutive pages by just placing them where you want (possibly) with a page clearing command in between.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your page size, the figures might be larger than a page.
In any case, there is no room for two of these figures on one page.

Try removing the `\newpage` macros.